# AWS CLI - aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --resource-type-filters excluding items on the results

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Good day,

I am currently working on a simple aws cli command. What I'm trying to do is get all resources that are missing a tag, the catch is that I am trying to exclude items on the result using

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --query 'ResourceTagMappingList[?Tags[?Key != `CheckedTag`]]'
```

I am trying to somehow filter the results to exclude some resource type like `cloudwatch:alarm` and came across the below command.

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --resource-type-filters cloudwatch:alarm
```

I know that the above command filters by resources but is there a way to like do the opposite like specify the resources to be "excluded" on the result? I'm trying exclude `cloudwatch:alarm` and `ec2:instance`

Link to documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/resourcegroupstaggingapi/get-resources.html

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --resource-type-filters cloudwatch:alarm
```